# How do I copy user input into a Structure in C?

Tags: c

I'm learning how to use structures in C, and I'm not sure how to scanf user input into a structure...
Here's the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    double x,y;
    char name;  // MUST BE SINGLE UPPERCASE LETTER
} pointType;

typedef struct {
    pointType A, B; // line segment defined by two points
    int slopeDefined;   // 1 if slope is defined and 0 in undefined
    double slope;       // rise/run = y2-y1 / x2-x1
}lineSegType;
```

Here's the code I'm using to try and copy user input into those fields in the structure:

```
void getPoint (pointType *P){
    printf("Enter your x-coordinate: ");
    scanf("%lf",&P->x);
    printf("Enter your y-coordinate: ");
    scanf("%lf",&P->y);
}
void getLineSeg (lineSegType *lSeg){
    printf("Enter first point name (single uppercase letter): ");
    scanf("%c",&lSeg->A.name);
    getPoint(&lSeg->A);
    printf("Enter second point name (single uppercase letter): ");
    scanf("%c",&lSeg->B.name);
    getPoint(&lSeg->B);
}
```

The program skips the "printf("Enter first point name (single uppercase letter): ");" and "printf("Enter second point name (single uppercase letter): ");" and doesn't copy the user entered coordinates to the x and y fields in the structure :/

Comment: Can you post your `main()`?

Comment: Do you want the whole thing or just main because the functions I shared are called from other functions...

Comment: To have good answers is better to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&lSeg->A.name);` and `scanf(" %c",&lSeg->B.name);` (note the addition of a `space` before `%c`) The `%c` conversion specifier does NOT skip leading whitespace (the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by the user pressing **Enter**) So the `'\n'` left from `scanf("%lf",&P->y);` is taken as input by `scanf("%c",&lSeg->A.name);` as you have it. (note: `%c`, `%[..]` and `%n` are the only conversion specifiers that do NOT discard leading whitespace)

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/ByHqLo9E_

Comment: Ok cool it works now :) thank you

Comment: Additionally, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. So change your function type from `void` to, e.g. `int` and validate every `if (scanf("%lf",&P->x) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid numeric input.\n", stderr); return 0; }` That way you communicate the success or failure of the read back to the calling function. (whether you use `0` or `1` to indicate error is up to you) You also need a way to empty `stdin` in case of a *matching-failure*. (search this site `"[c] scanf matching failure"`)

Comment: @ChrisHappy - if you would like to write it up, I'll leave that to you. Feel free to copy/paste from any of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `scanf(" %c", &ptr);`

Note the addition of a space.

The `%c` conversion specifier does NOT skip leading whitespace (the `\n` remaining in `stdin` by the user pressing `Enter`). So the `\n` remaining from `scanf("%lf",&P->y);` is taken as input by `scanf("%c",&lSeg->A.name);` as you have it.

Note: `%c`, `%[..]` and `%n` are the only conversion specifiers that do NOT discard leading whitespace.

Also, you cannot use any input function correctly unless you check the return. So change your function type from `void` to a value like `int` and validate every `scanf` with:

```
if (scanf("%lf",&P->x) != 1) {
    fputs ("error: invalid numeric input.\n", stderr);
    return 1; // non zero error code. 0 could also work
}
```

That way you communicate the success or failure of the read back to the calling function.

You also need a way to empty stdin in case of a matching-failure. (search this site "[c] scanf matching failure")

https://replit.com/@chrishappy/Debug-copy-user-input-into-a-Structure-in-C#main.c

Comment: ok it works for the coordinates but the program will skips over the point name input :/